# multiple database connection in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, datamapper

can i connection with multiple database
main connections is from database.php

but the another one in from the model
and i want to switch between it

like this

```
        $config['remote']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $config['remote']['username'] = 'root';
        $config['remote']['password'] = '';
        $config['remote']['database'] = 'countries';
        $config['remote']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
        $config['remote']['dbprefix'] = '';
        $config['remote']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
        $config['remote']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $config['remote']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
        $config['remote']['cachedir'] = '';
        $config['remote']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
        $config['remote']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
        $config['remote']['swap_pre'] = '';
        $config['remote']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
        $config['remote']['stricton'] = FALSE;

        $this->load->database($config);

        $this->load->database('remote', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax to use multiple database is following.

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
```

The only difference Here is that you have to use the returned database object.

See notes on [code igniter user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html) on *Connecting to Multiple Databases* section

> Note: Change the words "group_one" and "group_two" to the specific group names you are connecting to (or you can pass the connection values as indicated above).
>
> By setting the second parameter to TRUE (boolean) the function will return the database object.

Comment: i wont to config the second database from **Model**

Comment: or if i can to pass parameter to database.php file

Comment: The method I described above works on any class. It can be controller or Model whatever. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#conn

Comment: @dev.bashar In other way just use the code in your model it will work.